FOSS Windows backup to incremental VHDX files?
Is there any backup software, preferably free & open-source, that can make incremental backups of Windows disks formatted as VHDX files?
While there are a number of existing FOSS incremental backup solutions that can be used on Windows, they all seem to have proprietary file formats. I really value having my backups in a file type that can be explored or restored on a different device without requiring a specific 3rd-party program.
